# Getting empty result while trying to query in mongo db collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to implement login api with node js and mongo db, but unfortunately 
I am always getting empty response or "cannot read property password of undefined".
When I do  CurrentUser.find().exec(function(err, user) {}); - it do brings all my collections.

I have this kind of model:

users.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;
const UserSchema = Schema({  
   firstname: { type: String, required: true },  
   lastname: { type: String, required: true },  
   email: { type: String, required: true },  
   password: { type: String, required: true }
}); 
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

my router.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const AlbuMmodel = require('../src/lib/models/album');
const UserModel = require('../src/lib/models/users');
const CurrentUser = require('../src/lib/models/users');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/shopdb');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(session({secret: 'qwerty', saveUninitialized: true, resave: false}));

exports.loginUser = function (req, res){    
  var useremail = req.body.email;
  var psw = req.body.password;

   CurrentUser.find({email:useremail}).exec(function(err, user) {
    if(err){
        return res.send({"status":"500","message":"There is a problem. Please try later"});
    }   
    if(!user){
        return res.send({"status":"410", "message":"Invalid password or email"});
    }       
    if (!err) {         
        if(psw == user[0].password){
            req.session.user = user;
            return res.send(user[0]);
        } 
        else{
            return res.send({"status":"410", "message":"Invalid password or email"});
        }

    } 
    else{
        req.session.reset();
        return res.send({"status":"400", "message":"Invalid password or email"});
    }       
});
};
```

In database collection is saved and named like: users

Comment: first try to console req.body.password and see is it coming from client side.

Comment: Yes I can see it. I think the problem either in query or in collection name. mongo returns empty object

Comment: It would be better to use `findOne` here instead of `find` as you're only expecting a single matching doc and it would make it easier to debug.

Comment: I have a question: my db collection is named users. In mongoose.model must be user or users? Now it is: module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

Comment: You can set the collection name in the schema. Here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection